# Clear modal content for remote content when Modal is closed

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This works well except it takes a few seconds (most I've seen is 5 secs) for the data to load. How can I have it so that if I click on a different link it will clear the modal content and not show the previous info?

## HTML Code

```
<a href="/jira/$jira_ticket" rel="modal" class="btn bg-teal-400">View Jira Ticket</a>
```

## JS Code

```
$('a[rel=modal]')
    .on('click', function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var modal = $('#modal').modal();
        modal
            .find('.modal-body')
            .load($(this).attr('href'), function (responseText, textStatus) {
                if ( textStatus === 'success' ||
                     textStatus === 'notmodified')
                {
                    modal.show();
                }
        });                
});

$('a[rel=modal]')
    .on('hidden.bs.modal', function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var modal = $('#modal').modal();
        modal
            .find('.modal-body')
            .text()
});
```

Comment: Replace the modal-body with empty content when the modal is closed. And when you load new content, you will just see an empty box.

Comment: See edits, doesn't seem to be working.